# selenium: <a> tag with href click behavior wrong

Tags: python, selenium

My testing website has an element like this:

```
<a href="http://t.qq.com/p/t/148892114342486" class="comt" num="1">评论</a>
```

There is some javascript hooked with the  tag and the desired behavior is when clicking  tag, the browser will not go anywhere but stay in the same page, open a comment textarea for user to input.

But in selenium, both happened, the textarea is opened and the browser will navigate to the page that href points to, which is not desired result for my selenium scripts.

How to avoid this?

I am thinking of changing the href attribute to "#" to avoid such problem but looks like the selenium itself can't change the element in the webpage, is that true?

My python selenium script:

```
ask = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='comt']")
ask.click()
```

Comment: does your javascript contain a "return false;" statement at the end? did you try the fireEvent function? sometimes (for me, at least) launching directly click() fails on some ajax

Comment: http://t.qq.com/yilanyeh

Comment: The javascript is not written by me... fireEvent in selenium?

Comment: use br.execute_script() to modify the content.

Comment: Make sure there should be only one locator corresponding to your desired behavior. I think it is clicking on some other tag rather your desired one.

Answer (score 0):

As the above users's commented ...since a JS is hooked with the click event over the hyperlink.

Then it's suggested to fire the JavaScript Event directly rather than focusing on click event over hyperlink..

From above url you commented, I took the following element

```
<a title="" onmousedown="MI.Bos('btnVaryEntrance1')" onclick="vary('yilanyeh','叶怡兰');" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

It had a JS function ***vary('yilanyeh','叶怡兰')*** hooked over Click event...so My code looks like this (C# Code)

```
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://t.qq.com/yilanyeh");

        IJavaScriptExecutor jr = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

        jr.ExecuteScript("vary('yilanyeh','叶怡兰');");
```